# Master Data Services- Merge members

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2012, master-data-services, master-data-management

Can any one tell me how to merge two members in an MDS entity using C# as Codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use EntityMembersMerge function. Here is the function details:

```
public void EntityMemberMerge(string modelName, string versionName, string entityName, string memberCode, string newMemberName)
```